# Regular Expression to get LastName / FirstName from a text

Tags: c#, regex

I've a text file like :

```
67890                    LastName, FirstName                                                                          
09/10/2020 18:18:01                               Page 1 of 1
DOB    01/01/1982     38 years         Male
..........
```

I would to extract LastName, First Name  separately, then with 2
regexp to grab:

- **LastName** as all the Chars before the first comma "," removing spaces
  before it.
- **FirstName** as all the chars after the first comma "," removing spaces
  after it.

I did a test for the LastName with (C#):

```
^.*?(?=,)
```

but is grabbing all before the comma , not just the LastName.

Also the Code :

```
(?<=^.{20})([^,])+
```

is grabbing 20 chars before the comma but includes the Spaces. I Would just grab all chars before comma, could also be 20 chars before comma not to include the initial numbers.

I'm using the Test Site :

http://regexstorm.net/tester

Many Thanks for help!

Comment: 1. `\S+(?=,)`, 2. `(?<=,\s*)\S+`?

Comment: `\b([^,\s]+),\s(.+?)\b` would put the last name in to capture group #1 and firstname into #2. https://regex101.com/r/m88RbW/1

Comment: please print more input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Last name extraction regex**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%5B%5E%2C%5D*%3F%5Cs%2B%29%5CS%2B%28%3F%3D%2C%29&i=67890%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20LastName%2C%20FirstName%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A09%2F10%2F2020%2018%3A18%3A01%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Page%201%20of%201%0D%0ADOB%20%20%20%2001%2F01%2F1982%20%20%20%20%2038%20years%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Male):

```cs
(?<=^[^,]*?\s+)\S+(?=,)
```

[**First name extraction regex**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%2C%5Cs*%29%5CS%2B&i=67890%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20LastName%2C%20FirstName%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A09%2F10%2F2020%2018%3A18%3A01%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Page%201%20of%201%0D%0ADOB%20%20%20%2001%2F01%2F1982%20%20%20%20%2038%20years%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Male):

```cs
(?<=,\s*)\S+
```

Comment: Thank you , the solution is perfect !!